# How to optimize api response in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have list of articles. they contain category and sub-category.

```
const articles = [ { name, ..., category: { name, … , subCategories: [{ name, ... }] } } ]
```

I have api endpoint that I send all my articles with category and subCategories (it is mandatory).

The problem is category and subcategories are repeats (and it can be big data to send), the same category and subcategory is in article1 and article90 for example.

I think about to exclude category from the article, just replace with an `id` 
and create another property category, and send them back to the client.

```
res.json({ categories: [{ name: "1", ... , subCategories }], articles: [{ name , …, category: "1" }] });
```

How to that in easy way and generic for all my objects that repeat data in nodejs?

Comment: How are you loading the categories? I would send them all rather than using multiple requests.

Comment: all object come from mongodb, each object have ref to another. for example, article have category which ref to Category scheme.

Comment: It doesn't exist any popular solution for this IMO. Most of APIs send all the info available to keep client simple. Even Google APIs send responses of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think depends on the what you application need to display. But a common solution is using pagination (e.g., getting chunks of 10 unities) in the API and, then, handling the pagination in the frontend.

Other solution is having some kind of consolidation. For example, if you would list all reads of a device in a interval, that sends data to server every 5 seconds, you could run a background service to consolidate data and save a mean of all values. Then, the frontend would get the mean at the interval, not actually all reads .